# Why Graphic Card should be installed so we can Hibernate/Sleep our computers?

Tags: windows, power-management

I've always wonder why graphic cards should be installed on windows so we can Hibernate/Sleep our computers?

Comment: consumes more power?

Comment: A graphics card has nothing to do with whether you computer can hibernate/sleep.  I'm sorry but your question is rather unclear, is there any way you could rephrase it to tell us what you are actually wanting to know?